# ngx-select take typed value

Tags: angular, angular6

```
<ngx-select #drop [items]="dropdownReci" [(ngModel)]="values">
        <ng-template ngx-select-option-not-found>
          There is no result, <button (click)="add(drop.value)"><b>add it</b></button>.
        </ng-template>
</ngx-select>
```

I am trying to take value when ngx-select search don't find anything, so i can add it. I have "value" array that works if i choose searched strings. How could i get value that is typed in the moment?

Answer (score 0):

in ngx-select i added:

```
(keyup)="onKeyUp($event)"
```

and in component.ts i added:

```
val: string = "";
onKeyUp(event): void {
    event.stopPropagation();

    const key = event.key;
    const value = event.target.value;
    this.val= value;
  }
```

And now on "keyup" event i get letter by letter and put it in val, so if i don't have results on click add i will add that val to string[].